# Opening JQuery Ui Dialog in MousePosition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i want to open JQuery UI Dialog In Mouse Position.
what is the problem with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var x;
        var y;
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
        });

        $("#d").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            position: [x, y]
        });
        $("#c").bind("mouseover", function () {
            $("#d").dialog('open'); // open
        });


        $("#c").bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $("#d").dialog('close'); // open
        });



    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Updating `x` and `y` after they're passed (by value) to *setup* the dialog won't have any effect, since the variables aren't related after that.  You'll need to update the position option directly, like this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    $("#d").dialog("option", { position: [e.pageX, e.pageY] });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pgA5P/), or the much more optimized version (since you only show it on top of `#c` anyway):

```
$(function () {
    $("#d").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });
    $("#c").hover(function () {
        $("#d").dialog('open');
    }, function () {
        $("#d").dialog('close');
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#d").dialog("option", { position: [e.pageX+5, e.pageY+5] });
    });
});
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pgA5P/2/).

Comment: not working. it is not close to mouspointer, somewhere in middle of screen

Answer (score 10):

The answer of Nick Craver works, only need an improvement, in order to the box be always near the cursor.

The Y-axis needs to be subtracted by the scrollTop of the page.
So that line becomes:

```
$("#d").dialog("option", { position: [e.pageX+5, (e.pageY+5)-$(document).scrollTop()] });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#d").dialog(
    "option", 
    {
        position: 
        {
            my: 'left', 
            at: 'right', 
            of: event
        }
    }
);
```

Working sample: http://jsbin.com/okosi4

This solution worked better for me when I had a long page that required scrolling. I found the above solutions didn't work well with vertical scrolling.

See more about **[position option](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)**

Comment: I followed the "Working sample" link, but it says the "free preview time has expired"

Comment: so... copy paste the content to a fiddle or similar.