# Difference results using PageY and ClientY mouse positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

My question is similar to [Opening JQuery Ui Dialog in MousePosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552503/opening-jquery-ui-dialog-in-mouseposition), however differs in that I want the Jquery Dialog Box to be shown very close to the button which was clicked. My current issue is that when I set the `position` attribute, the Dialog box is show at the bottom of the page when using

```
$("button.deleteEmailRow").live("click", function (e) {

    var target = this
    $("#emailAddress").html(this.name); // not imp for my problem
    $("#dialog-email-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: false,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: 'dialogs-only',
        buttons: {
            "Delete Email Recipient": function () {//snip; 
                                     return false;},
            "Cancel": function () {//snip;  
                                     return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $("#dialog-email-confirm")
          .dialog('option', 'position', [e.pageX+30, e.pageY])
          .dialog('open');
});
```

However, when using the following, it works as intended.

```
    $("#dialog-email-confirm")
          .dialog('option', 'position', [e.clientX+30, e.clientY])
          .dialog('open');
```

According to the [Jquery website](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), the first script should work.

> *When tracking mouse movement, you usually need to know the actual
>   position of the mouse pointer. The event object that is passed to the 
>   handler contains some information about the mouse coordinates. 
>   Properties such as .clientX, .offsetX, and .pageX are available, but 
>   support for them differs between browsers. Fortunately, jQuery 
>   normalizes the .pageX and .pageY properties so that they can be used 
>   in all browsers. These properties provide the X and Y coordinates of 
>   the mouse pointer relative to the top-left corner of the document, as 
>   illustrated in the example output above.*

I checked to make sure that values are the same using the following and found that there was a a difference with regards to the Y-coordinates.

```
var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
alert(pageCoords + '\n' + clientCoords);
```

I have read through [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos), and also played around with [some test code](http://jsfiddle.net/KDjdK/) which behaves as expected. Why is above producing difference results in my script? Is is related to my HTML structure?

Edit (Updated HTML):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/960.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/themes/liberty/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/themes/dialogs-only/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/sexybuttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Scripts/messagebar/skins/plain/skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div id="header" class="container_12"></div>
      <div id="menuwrapper"></div>
      <div id="content" class="container_12">
        <div id="main" class="grid_12 alpha omega">
          <h2>
            Configuration Settings
          </h2>
          <form action="/Settings/Edit" method="post">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Settings</legend> // snip
              <div class="editor-label">
                <label for="EmailSuccessList">List of recipients for Successful Notifications</label>
              </div>
              <div class="editor-field">
                <fieldset>
                  <input type="hidden" name="EmailSuccessList.index" autocomplete="off" value="4eedd5a0-076b-4bc6-9a07-7455df9c5d83"><input type="hidden" name="EmailSuccessList.index" autocomplete="off" value="151d8ad0-f204-445c-8778-5207ddbae952"><input type="hidden" name="EmailSuccessList.index" autocomplete="off" value="7b51d4b0-78b6-4ccd-a886-ffef9fe8a00f"><input type="hidden" name="EmailSuccessList.index" autocomplete="off" value="0c7f4c5f-7344-4b47-9202-3ff61ce843fc">
                  <table id="editorEmailSuccessRows" class="editorEmailSuccessRows">
                    <tr class="editorRow">
                      <td class="emailRow">
                        <input class="text-box single-line" id="EmailSuccessList_4eedd5a0-076b-4bc6-9a07-7455df9c5d83_" name="EmailSuccessList[4eedd5a0-076b-4bc6-9a07-7455df9c5d83]" type="text" value="abcs@test.com">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" href="#" id="deleteEmailRow" class="deleteEmailRow" name="abcs@test.com"><span><span><span class="delete">delete</span></span></span></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="editorRow">
                      <td class="emailRow">
                        <input class="text-box single-line" id="EmailSuccessList_151d8ad0-f204-445c-8778-5207ddbae952_" name="EmailSuccessList[151d8ad0-f204-445c-8778-5207ddbae952]" type="text" value="abcs@test.com">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" href="#" id="deleteEmailRow" class="deleteEmailRow" name="abcs@test.com"><span><span><span class="delete">delete</span></span></span></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="editorRow">
                      <td class="emailRow">
                        <input class="text-box single-line" id="EmailSuccessList_7b51d4b0-78b6-4ccd-a886-ffef9fe8a00f_" name="EmailSuccessList[7b51d4b0-78b6-4ccd-a886-ffef9fe8a00f]" type="text" value="abcs@test.com">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" href="#" id="deleteEmailRow" class="deleteEmailRow" name="abcs@test.com"><span><span><span class="delete">delete</span></span></span></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="editorRow">
                      <td class="emailRow">
                        <input class="text-box single-line" id="EmailSuccessList_0c7f4c5f-7344-4b47-9202-3ff61ce843fc_" name="EmailSuccessList[0c7f4c5f-7344-4b47-9202-3ff61ce843fc]" type="text" value="abcs@test.com">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button" href="#" id="deleteEmailRow" class="deleteEmailRow" name="abcs@test.com"><span><span><span class="delete">delete</span></span></span></button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="3" align="right" class="lastRow">
                        <a href='/Settings/BlankEmailEditorRow?collectionName=EmailSuccessList' class=" sexysimple sexygreen" id='addNewSuccessEmail'><span class="add">Add new recipient</span></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </fieldset>
              </div><button type="submit" value="Save Configuration" id="save" name="save"></button> <a href="/Settings" id="cancelEdit">Cancel</a>
              <div class="cancel" style="display: none">
                <div id="dialog-confirm-cancel" title="Cancel Edit?" class="diag">
                  <p>
                    Any changes you have made will not be saved.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="demo" style="display: none">
                <div id="dialog-email-confirm" title="Delete Email?" class="dialogs-only">
                  <p>
                    Are you sure you wish to delete this recipient from the list : <span id="emailAddress" style="font-weight: bold;"></span>?
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
          <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Tests using Google Chrome v14*

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/SUYA7/ for full sample.

Comment: Almost definitely related to your HTML and CSS, which is missing from the question. Please provide a working example of the problem.

Comment: I don't have your CSS on my computer. Can you provide a working example in jsFiddle?

Comment: @andyb - http://jsfiddle.net/SUYA7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pageX/pageY you are using document/page relative position but jQuery dialog expects position relative to the viewport.

Comment: Won't that be the same thing? My document is as wide and as tall as my viewport ( which is ' viewport is not an HTML construct, so you cannot influence it by CSS' http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)

Answer (score 1):

Although not the cause of the problem, there are multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid HTML. The following markup occurs 4 times in the example:

```
<button type="button" href="#" id="deleteEmailRow" class="deleteEmailRow button sexybutton" name="abc.test@com"><span><span><span class="delete">delete</span></span></span></button>
```

The problem is that the `position` option in the jQuery UI dialog *needs*

> > an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of **viewport** (e.g. [350,100])

so you cannot use `<event.pageX, event.pageY>` since they provide the X and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to the top-left corner of the *document*. You need to provide client co-ordinates.