# How can I control where a jquery-ui Dialog displays?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Here's what I'm doing:

1) Add a "hide" CSS class:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

2) Add some HTML to where the Dialog should display, hiding it by default, such as:

```
  <div class="hide" id="postTSec4" name="postTSec4">
    <h2>Post-Travel Bottom</h2>
    <img id="imgPostTravelBottom" name="imgPostTravelBottom" src="images/4_PTE_Bottom_Jig.png" alt="post Travel image" height="275" width="350">
  </div>
  <div class="hide" id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>
```

3) In response to some event, unhide the div and call dialog() on it, such as:

```
$( "#dialog" ).removeClass('hide');
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```

The problem is that this causes the dialog to display in the middle of the page; I want the dialog to display with its NW corner at the tip of the cursor/pointer/finger.

So how can I control where the dialog appears?

### UPDATE

I used the linked-to, supposedly-the-answer code as a basis, but no, it doesn't quite work in my situation.

### UPDATE 2

With this code (adapted from meteorBuzz's answer):

CSS

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    border: 2px green solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
#dialog {
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    border: 3px black solid;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="postTravelSection5">
<div class="outer hide" id="postTSec5" name="postTSec5">
    <div id="dialog" name="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is dialog content area...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.postTravelSection5.events({
    'click #postTSec5': function(event) { 
      var x = event.pageX;
      var y = event.pageY;

      $("#dialog")
        .offset({
          'left': x,
          'top': y
        });
    }
  });

  Template.postTravel.events({
    'click #imgPostTravel': function() {
      . . .
      $('#postTSec5').removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
```

("outer" and "dialog" are seen after "imgPostTravel" is clicked).

...it does not work; I see the two divs (the outer one with the green border, and the div dialog within it), but clicking does nothing.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: I looked at that but can't decode it; it's a little too abstract, IMO - I want a concrete example.

Comment: This has nothing to do with meteor and positioning by mouse position is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552503/opening-jquery-ui-dialog-in-mouseposition

Comment: @B.ClayShannon In the future, if you HAVE read the docs, pointing to them will show that you have at least done a bit of research. Looking at your question as is, it looks like you simply tried `.dialog()`, found it positioning in center, and then asked here how to move it without doing any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have full control of the div behaviour by simply creating your own behaviour model instead of using jquery-ui for this particular matter. 
Also, you can make the dialog look unique instead of having to over-ride jquery-ui default styling and positioning.

You may move the div to where the click event took place in two steps:

1. Capture x/y coordinates of the click event
2. Set these values to the styling of the div using javascript.

Notice, I've created an `#outer` div that spans most of the web page to allow the `#dialog` div to move within such a space.

HTML

```
<template name="postTravelSection4">
<div class="outer">
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is dialog content area...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.postTravelSection4.events({
  'click': function(event) { // you may add which element fires this function when you click it.
    var x = event.pageX; // x coordinates 
    var y = event.pageY; // y coordinates 

    $( "#dialog" )
      .offset({
        'left': x,
        'top': y
      });
    }

  });
}
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    border: 2px green solid;
    padding: 10px;
}

#dialog {
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    border: 3px black solid;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100; // incase of overlaps of divs, this one will remain on top
}
// create your hide/show classes to display and remove the div from display in the way you wish
```